# Forward Slash is removed in path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have set the html from code behind in ItemDataBound event of repeater but in html path is not right.

```
Dim video_path = imgUrl + VideoPath + VideoName.split(".")(0) + ".mp4"
        Dim poster_path = imgUrl + VideoPath + VideoName.split(".")(0) + ".png"
        Dim DvVidContent As HtmlContainerControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("DvVidContent"), HtmlContainerControl)
  Dim onclick = "'ShowVideoDialog('size_vp_" + count.ToString() + "', '" + video_path.ToString().Trim() + "');'"      
        Dim Header As String = "<div style='position:relative;'  Sequence='" + count.ToString() + "' id='" + ID.ToString() + "' class='SessionFolderViewChild'><img onerror='handleError(this);' src='" + poster_path.ToString() + "' alt='Thumbnail'/><img class='dv_play_icon' onclick='" + onclick + "' id='PlayVideo' style='position:absolute;top:8px;left:26px;height:100px;width:100px;' src='../../Images/icn_Play.png'/></a></div>"
        DvVidContent.InnerHtml = Header.Trim()
        count = count +
```

After Html rendering its remove the forward slash and look like

onclick="ShowVideoDialog("size_vp_1','.. .. resources sbs attachments steps351 step565 130906720751358852.mp4');

Comment: We need to see how the variable `onclick` gets created.

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with the `onclick` variable. Did you post the wrong snippet?

Comment: Dim onclick = "'ShowVideoDialog('size_vp_" + count.ToString() + "', '" + video_path.ToString().Trim() + "');'"

Comment: It's impossible to help unless you post a *reproducible* snippet. Only the first line seems relevant to the problem. Without knowing the *contents* of `imgUrl`, `VideoPath`, or `VideoName` it's impossible to help. Most likely, these variables don't contain any slashes to begin with

Comment: Also, `VideoName.split(".")(0)` is going to break if your original filename contains dots. Use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`.